# Strange behavior for the date() function linux

Tags: bash, date

I have found a strange behaviour for the date() function when using bash.
When I use date -d "2008-10-12 +1 days", the date function returned

date: invalid date ‘2008-10-12 +1days’

Even it returned error when trying:

date -d "2008-10-12"
--> date: invalid date ‘2008-10-12’

However, it works for:

date -d "2008-10-13 +1days"
--> Tue Oct 14 00:00:00 CLST 2008

date -d "2008-10-11 +1days"
--> Sun Oct 12 01:00:00 CLST 2008

date -d "2007-10-12 +1days"
--> Sat Oct 13 00:00:00 CLT 2007

... and so on

It seems the date() does not recognize "just" 2008-10-12. Is it a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

I am using CENTOS 7

All the best

Comment: @aergistal, yes, that is probably it, I would also say that it is a daylight savings issue.

Comment: Solve the problem by changing the time as YYYY/MM/DD to seconds ... This avoid to have the problem with daylight savings, which depends on your zone.

Answer (score 0):

In RHEL 7 there were many changes happened to somany commands. To change the time and date earlier we used to use `date` command and now we need to use `timedatectl` command (preferred) instead.

http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/timedatectl.html

So as there is a new latest command with more features included they might have limited it (Not sure on that). But from this version I have been using `timedatectl` command which is really great one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments .. this help me a lot in discovering the zone of my computer ... after that I could use zdump to see exactly when the problem will appears ...